# Where do std::bind-created functors live?

Tags: c++, bind, std, functor

A function pointer can point to anything from a free function, a function object, a wrapper over a member function call.

However, the std::bind created functors can have state, as well as custom-created ones. Where that state is allocated, and who is deleting it?

Consider the below example - will the state ( the number 10) be deleted when the vector is deleted? Who know to call a deleter on the functor, and no deleter on the function pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;
class Bar
{
    public:
    void bar(int x, int y) { cout << "bar" << endl; }
};
void foo(int baz){ cout << "foo" << endl; }
int main() {
    typedef std::function<void(int)> Func;

    std::vector<Func> funcs;
    funcs.push_back(&foo); // foo does not have to be deleted
    Bar b;
    // the on-the-fly functor created by bind has to be deleted
    funcs.push_back(std::bind(&Bar::bar, &b, 10, _1)); 

    // bind creates a copy of 10. 
    // That copy does not go into the vector, because it's a vector of pointers.
    // Where does it reside? Who deletes it after funcs is destroyed?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::bind return you a functor, which hold the copy of values and manage it

Comment: "...because it's a vector of pointers..." No, its a vector of `std::function<void(int)>`. A vector of function pointers would be `std::vector<void (*)(int)>`.

Comment: The same problem is already present in the very first line: "A function pointer can point to ... a function object". No, it can't. Function pointers can point to free functions, static methods of classes and non-capturing lambda's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::bind` returns an object by value (the object's exact type is an implementation detail of the standard library). This object stores all necessary state and its destructor does all the required cleanup.

Notice that your vector does not store pointers - it stores `std::function` objects. A `std::function` object internally stores the object from which it was created (a function pointer or the object returned by `std::bind` in your case), and its destructor correctly destroys the stored object. Destroying a pointer to function does nothing. Destroying an object of class type invokes its destructor.

Comment: That's a good deal of info, but it does not answer how std::function calls the destructor. Is bind() creating a derived object that's polymorphically deleted?

Comment: @sammy: In a word, yes, but no. `std::function` does. It implements the C++ *type erasure* idiom. Look this up.

Comment: Does this mean that if - having a variable of type 'Func' - I reassign this variable with some new 'bind', the previous object is automatically deleted?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek The previous object held internally inside the `std::function` object is automatically destroyed, yes. Just like when you assign into a `std::vector`, the objects held in it previously are destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: "automatically" here does not mean that it is destroyed by i.e. "going out of scope"? It is intentional action of std::function upon reassignment?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I'd say that's an implementaiton detail of `std::function`, really. It does proper cleanup, that's all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function creates an instance of an unspecified class, and when that object goes out of scope and is destructed, so is the storage for that instance.

Just like instances of any other class with a destructor that releases some resource.